# How can i setup a Project using Jersey, Spring, Hibernate and maven

Tags: java-8, maven-3, jersey-2.0, spring-4, hibernate-5.x

How can I configure a Java project using below libraries?

1. Jersey 2.25
2. Spring 4.3.5 RELEASE
3. Hibernate 5.5.6 Final
4. Apache Maven
5. Java 8

Comment: Please change this to a question/answer format

Comment: i had to face a lot of problem to find such solution. so i thought of providing the solution at one place, so that others can take a benefit of it and don't have to pull their head looking all around.

Comment: Yes that's great. But it should be in a Q&A format. Post an actual question. Then post your solution to it as an answer below. Self-answer questions are very much welcome, as long as they are in the correct Q&A format

Comment: I have changed it. kindly check, if i am correct or not.

Comment: You should post the solution in an answer **below**, not in your question. So just copy and paste the solution into an answer **below** (and take it out of the question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Project is based on JERSEY 2.25, SPRING 4.3.5 RELEASE, HIBERNATE 5.5.6 Final, USING MAVEN**

**I thought of sharing my knowledge on creating basic setup, to give a kick start to your project.** I am placing this request, because i couldn't find any complete solution for JERSEY-SPRING-HIBERNATE setup and configuration. As i went through a lot to problem to find the solution. 
You can also refer to my Github project [Jersey-Spring-Hibernate-Project](https://github.com/prayagkr/Jersey-Spring-Hibernate-Project)
.

---

**To start a project open Eclipse IDE.**

File -> new -> other -> Maven -> Maven Project -> press Next -> press Next

in the filter, look for  **jersey-quickstart-webapp with version 2.24** or later.

if you don't find it, then click **Add Archetype**

Archetype Group id : **org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes**

Archetype Artifact id: **jersey-quickstart-webapp**

Archetype Version: **2.24**

Repository URL: leave it empty

Press OK.

Now again follow steps from start and now you will find **jersey-quickstart-webapp with version 2.24**.

select it and press NEXT.

Provide your **Group id:** "which will be your package name", in my case it is **org.pramod**.

provide your **Artifact id:** "This is your project name"

**Package:** in this project is  **org.pramod**

click Finish

---

**To setup our project we need 4 files to configure.**

1. web.xml
2. pom.xml
3. applicationContext.xml
4. MyApplication.java

---

File name: **src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">

  <!-- REGISTERING LISTNER -->
  <listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>

  <!--  TO REGISTER THE BEANS -->  
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
<!-- TO REGISTER THE SERVLET which is mentioned in the MyApplication -->
    <init-param>
      <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
      <param-value>org.pramod.config.MyApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/webapi/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

---

File Name: **src/main/resources/applicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jerseyspringhibernate"/>
        <property name="username" value="root"/>
        <property name="password" value="root"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>org.pramod.model.Customer</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>
    <bean id="customerService" class="org.pramod.service.CustomerServiceImpl"/>
    <bean id="customerDao" class="org.pramod.dao.CustomerDaoImpl"/>

</beans>
```

---

File Name : **pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
     http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.pramod</groupId>
  <artifactId>JerseySpringHibernate</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>JerseySpringHibernate</name>

  <build>
     <finalName>JerseySpringHibernate</finalName>
       <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>

   <dependencyManagement>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
   </dependencyManagement>

   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
      </dependency>
<!--         
      <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>javax.servlet</artifactId>
                <groupId>servlet-api</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
      </dependency>
 -->       
<!-- ******************************************************** -->       
      <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>

<!-- ********************** SPRING 4.3.4 *****************************  -->

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
      </dependency>     
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
             </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-instrument</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-instrument-tomcat</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
          <version>${spring.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
          <version>${spring.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
          <version>${spring.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
          <version>${spring.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
          <version>${spring.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
          <version>${spring.version}</version>
      </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
          <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc-portlet</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-websocket</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

<!-- ********************* HIBERNATE 5.5.6 ************************* -->  

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

<!-- ********************* MY SQL CONNECTOR *************************  -->  

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.38</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <properties>    
        <jersey.version>2.25</jersey.version>
        <spring.version>4.3.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <hibernate.version>5.5.6.Final</hibernate.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

---

Below mentioned Files are all java files, which are placed in the **src/main/java/** followed by package name. Package name is **org.pramod**. Example **src/main/java/org.pramod.***

File Name : **org.pramod.config.MyApplication.java**

```
package org.pramod.config;

import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;

public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig{

    public MyApplication(){
        register(MyResource.class);
        register(CustomerResource.class);
    }
}
```

---

**THESE ARE THE SERVLET RESOURCE. 1. MyResource and  2. CustomerResource can be moved to org.pramod.resource package**

File Name : **org.pramod.config.MyResource.java**

```
package org.pramod.config;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import org.pramod.service.CustomerService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

/**
 * Root resource (exposed at "myresource" path)
 */
@Path("myresource")
public class MyResource {

    @Autowired
    CustomerService customerService;


    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getIt() {
        return customerService.getStringTest();
    }
}
```

---

File Name: **org.pramod.config.CustomerResource.java**

```
package org.pramod.config;

import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.DELETE;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import org.pramod.model.Customer;
import org.pramod.service.CustomerService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

@Path("customers")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class CustomerResource {

  @Autowired
  CustomerService customerService;

  @GET
  public List<Customer> getCustomers(){
    return customerService.getAllCustomer();
  }

  @GET
  @Path("/{customerId}")
  public Customer getCustomer(@PathParam("customerId") int id){
    return customerService.getCustomerById(id);
  }

  @POST
  public Customer saveCustomer(Customer customer){
    return customerService.addCustomer(customer);
  }

  @PUT
  @Path("/{customerId}")
  public Customer updateCustomer(@PathParam("customerId") int id, Customer customer){
    return customerService.updateCustomer(id, customer);
  }

  @DELETE
  @Path("/{customerId}")
  public Customer removeCustomer(@PathParam ("customerId") int id ){
    return customerService.deleteCustomer(id);
  }
}
```

---

**THESE ARE THE Spring Service Files and Interface. 1. CustomerService and  2. CustomerServiceImpl**

File Name: **org.pramod.service.CustomerService.java**

```
package org.pramod.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.pramod.model.Customer;

public interface CustomerService {

    String getStringTest();
    Customer addCustomer(Customer customer);
    Customer updateCustomer(int id, Customer customer);
    Customer deleteCustomer(int id);
    Customer getCustomerById(int id);
    List<Customer> getAllCustomer();
}
```

---

File Name: **org.pramod.service.CustomerServiceImpl.java**

```
package org.pramod.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.pramod.dao.CustomerDao;
import org.pramod.model.Customer;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

public class CustomerServiceImpl implements CustomerService {

  @Autowired
  private CustomerDao customerDao; 

  @Override
  public String getStringTest() {
    return customerDao.getStringTest();
  }

  @Override
  public Customer addCustomer(Customer customer) {
    return customerDao.addCustomer(customer);
  }

  @Override
  public Customer updateCustomer(int id, Customer customer) {
    return customerDao.updateCustomer(id, customer);
  }

  @Override
  public Customer deleteCustomer(int id) {
    return customerDao.deleteCustomer(id);
  }

  @Override
  public Customer getCustomerById(int id) {
    return customerDao.getCustomerById(id);
  }

  @Override
  public List<Customer> getAllCustomer() {
    return customerDao.getAllCustomer();
  }
}
```

---

**These are the  Hibernate Implementation Files and Interface.**

**1. CustomerDao and  2. CustomerDaoImpl.**

**If you dont want to implement HIBERNATE, than you can omit this two files and in the applicationContext.xml file DELETE the  bean with id's "dataSource" and "sessionFactory".  Remove the dependency of HIBERNATE in pom.xml**

---

File Name: **org.pramod.dao.CustomerDao.java**

```
package org.pramod.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.pramod.model.Customer;

public interface CustomerDao {

    String getStringTest();
    Customer addCustomer(Customer customer);
    Customer updateCustomer(int id, Customer customer);
    Customer deleteCustomer(int id);
    Customer getCustomerById(int id);
    List<Customer> getAllCustomer();

}
```

---

File Name: **org.pramod.dao.CustomerDaoImpl.java**

```
package org.pramod.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.pramod.model.Customer;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

public class CustomerDaoImpl implements CustomerDao {

  @Autowired
  SessionFactory sessionFactory;

  @Override
  public String getStringTest(){
    String save = "Got it";
    return save;
  }

  @Override
  public Customer addCustomer(Customer customer) {      
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    try{
        session.save(customer);
        tx.commit();
        return customer;
    }catch(Exception e){
        tx.rollback();
        return null;
    }
  }

  @Override
  public Customer updateCustomer(int id, Customer cust) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    try{
        Customer customer = cust;
        customer.setId(id);
        session.update(customer);
        tx.commit();
        return customer;
    }catch(Exception e){
        tx.rollback();
        return null;
    }
  }

  @Override
  public Customer deleteCustomer(int id) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    try{
        Customer cust = session.get(Customer.class,id);
        session.delete(cust);
        tx.commit();
        return cust;
    }catch(Exception e){
        tx.rollback();
        return null;
    }
  }

  @Override
  public Customer getCustomerById(int id) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    try{
        Customer cust = session.get(Customer.class,id);
        tx.commit();
        session.close();
        return cust;
    }catch(Exception e){
        tx.rollback();
        session.close();
        return null;
    }       
  }

  @Override
  public List<Customer> getAllCustomer() {
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    try{
        Query query = session.createQuery("from Customer");
        List<Customer> customers = query.list();
        tx.commit();
        session.close();
        return customers;
    }catch(Exception e){
        tx.rollback();
        session.close();
        return null;
    }       
  }

}
```

---

**This is the Entity or Object of Customer type. If you don't want to you use Hibernate. Remove All the annotation**

File Name: **org.pramod.model.Customer.java**

```
package org.pramod.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="CUSTOMER")
public class Customer {

  @Id @GeneratedValue
  @Column(name="customer_id")
  private int id;
  @Column
  private String firstName;
  @Column
  private String lastName;
  @Column
  private String street;
  @Column
  private String city;
  @Column
  private String state;
  @Column
  private int pin;

  public int getId() {
    return id;
  }
  public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
  }
  public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
  }
  public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
  }
  public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
  }
  public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
  }
  public String getStreet() {
    return street;
  }
  public void setStreet(String street) {
    this.street = street;
  }
  public String getCity() {
    return city;
  }
  public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
  }
  public String getState() {
    return state;
  }
  public void setState(String state) {
    this.state = state;
  }
  public int getPin() {
    return pin;
  }
  public void setPin(int pin) {
    this.pin = pin;
  }
}
```